# How to compare %d/%m/%Y strftime SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, select, strftime

I got some problems with this select :

```
 actu = "SELECT * FROM REGISTRO WHERE strftime('%d/%m/%Y',Fecha) BETWEEN strftime('%d/%m/%Y', '" + FechaIni + "') AND strftime('%d/%m/%Y','" + FechaFin + "') AND strftime('%H:%M:%S',Hora) BETWEEN strftime('%H:%M:%S', '" + HoraIni + "') AND strftime('%H:%M:%S','" + HoraFin + "')";
```

Where FechaIni and FechaFin are strings with values like: dd/mm/yyyy then... the sentence should be some like..:

```
 SELECT * FROM REGISTRO WHERE strftime('%d/%m/%Y',Fecha) BETWEEN strftime('%d/%m/%Y', '05/05/2014') AND strftime('%d/%m/%Y','31/12/2014')
```

I got like 300 rows in my database between my dates but nothing returns.

Thanks

Comment: So... that's what you're *expecting* the string concatenation to come out as, but what does it *actually* end up being?  I suspect the problem is with how you're forming your query.  In which case, you should **Use Prepared Statements**.  As an aside - I don't know much about sqlite, but the conversions you're doing seem unnecessary.

Comment: SELECT * FROM REGISTRO WHERE strftime('%H:%M:%S',Hora) BETWEEN strftime('%H:%M:%S', '" + HoraIni + "') AND strftime('%H:%M:%S','" + HoraFin + "')";
In this similar sentence the results are good, i use strftime cause i need let this format when i compare my string(FechaFin or 05/05/2014) with my database.
Thanks

Comment: What is the format of the values in the `Fecha` column?

Comment: And how are the fields arranged?

Comment: i can't understund your question